# Custom Constraint in Symfony 2 not being loaded

Tags: php, symfony, constraints, validation

I am using Symfony 2.0.12 and trying to create a custom constraint.

I have read the official documentation and some Stack Overflow questions but they don't help me...

I've created a file called Nif.php in Bundle/Validator/Constraints with the following content:

```
<?php

namespace XX\YYBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class NIF extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'El NIF introducido no es válido';
}
```

Then a file called NIFValidator.php in the same directory with the following content:

```
<?php

namespace XX\YYBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class NIFValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function isValid($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

And in the entity I import the validator with

```
use XX\YYBundle\Validator\Constraints as XXAssert;
```

and use it with the property...

```
/**
   @XXAssert/NifValidator()
 **/
```

But it doesn't seems to validate... I also tried to add a `die;` in the validator but the page seems to render without any problem...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with `@XXAssert\NIF()`  .